# Problems with symsum() function in Symbolic Math Toolbox

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math, toolbox

I'm having some problems when using the `symsum` function in MATLAB's Symbolic Math Toolbox. My code should be returning:

```
ans = sin(x) + x*cos(x) - x^2 / 2 * sin(x)
```

I think it has something to do with symbolic variables, but I'm new into MATLAB so help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
syms x i;
f(x) = sin(x);

symsum(x^i/factorial(i)*diff(f,x,i), i, 0, 2)
```

which returns `0` instead of the correct result indicated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because `diff(f,x,i)` evaluates to zero. When using [`symsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html), you need to be aware that, like with any Matlab function, the input arguments will be evaluated before being passed in. Just use a `for` loop (`sym/diff` is not vectorized in the third argument – see below):

```
syms x y;
f(x) = sin(x);
n = 0:2;
y = 0;
for i = n
    y = y+x^i/factorial(i)*diff(f,x,i);
end
```

Alternatively, you could try this form (in this case, for just three indexes, the above will probably be more efficient):

```
syms x y;
f(x) = sin(x);
n = 0:2; % Increasing orders of differentiation
y = diff(f,x,n(1));
yi = [y(x) zeros(1,length(n)-1)]; % To index into array, yi cannot be symfun
for i = 2:length(n)
    % Calculate next derivative from previous
    yi(i) = diff(yi(i-1),x,n(i)-n(i-1));
end
% Convert yi back to symfun so output is symfun
y = sum(x.^n./factorial(n).*symfun(yi,x));
```

Why does `diff(f,x,i)` evaluate to zero even though `i` is symbolic? From the documentation for [`sym/diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html):

> **diff**(S,n), for a positive integer n, differentiates S n times.
>    **diff**(S,'v',n) and **diff**(S,n,'v') are also acceptable.

In other words, the function doesn't support symbolic variables to specify the order of integration. The order, `n` (or `i` in your code) is also limited to a scalar. MuPAD's related functions have similar limitations as well unfortunately.

In my opinion, `sym/diff` should throw an error if it has this limitation rather than returning garbage. I'd recommend that you [file a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with The MathWorks to report this issue. You could also request that the function be updated to handle symbolic variables for the order of integration input.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to "cast" the symbolic i,j variables to double or integer before aplying diff() function?

It would be something like this 
symsum(x^i/factorial(i)*diff(f(x), double(i)), 0, 2)

Comment: @hectorhfm: That's effectively what the `for` loops in my answer do. You'll find that simply casting the symbolic variable `i` to a double results in an error. This is because `diff(f(x), double(i))` is still evaluated first before `i` is substituted for a numeric value provided by `symsum`. You can't cast an arbitrary symbolic variable (one with a name, but no value) to any numeric format because it's undefined.